# Scipy Circular Variance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

According to my understanding, circular variance has a range between 0 and 1. This is also confirmed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics)  as well as [here](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Circular_Data_Analysis.pdf). But for some reasons, circular variance function from `scipy.stats` gives values above 1.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import circmean, circvar

a = np.random.randint(0, high=360, size=10)

print(a)
print(circmean(a, 0, 360))
print(circvar(np.deg2rad(a)))
[143 116 152 172 349 152 182 306 345  81]
135.34974541954665
2.2576538466653857
```

Could somebody inform me why I am getting values above 1 from the function `circvar`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The less-helpful answer would be since that's how scipy defines it, so you'd better ask the developers to get a definite answer.
Really. the example from the docs is

```
from scipy.stats import circvar
circvar([0, 2*np.pi/3, 5*np.pi/3])
2.19722457734
```

So you can't say the behavior is unexpedected.
But why is it done that way?

Your second link defines the circular variance for a set of n angles a_1, ... a_n as

> V = 1 − \hat{R_1}

Where

> \hat{R_1} = R_1 / n
>   R_1 = \sqrt{C^2 + S^2}

and

> C = \sum_{i=1}^n cos(a_i)
>   S = \sum_{i=1}^n sin(a_i)

The scipy library finds the circular variance by

```
ang = (samples - low)*2.*pi / (high - low)
S = sin(ang).mean(axis=axis)
C = cos(ang).mean(axis=axis)
R = hypot(S, C)
return ((high - low)/2.0/pi)**2 * 2 * log(1/R)
```

That's a bit tricky to understand.
If we assume the samples are zero-mean, the range is [0, 2*pi], and the default axis is being used (all true in the example) it can be simplified to

```
S = mean(sin(samples))
C = mean(cos(samples))
R = hypot(S, C)
V = 2 * log(1/R)
```

So the definition used by scipy transforms R by 2*log(1/R), rather than 1-R.
That seems odd.
Looking through the history, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blame/v1.1.0/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L2696-L2733, at one point the stats were calculated using

```
ang = (samples - low)*2*pi / (high-low)
res = stats.mean(exp(1j*ang))
V = 1-abs(res)
return ((high-low)/2.0/pi)**2 * V
```

Which seems in line with the definitions you've provided.
That was changed in a bugfix at the same time tests were added, but without any reference as to where the new computations came from.

Some discussion on the scipy bug tracker is available at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5747.
It suggests the behavior is intentional, and won't be fixed.
There's another implementation available in astropy, http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.circvar.html, which notes

> The definition used here differs from the one in scipy.stats.circvar. Precisely, Scipy circvar uses an approximation based on the limit of small angles which approaches the linear variance.

So, in summary, for unknown reasons `scipy` uses an approximation (that seems to be rather poor in some cases).  However, due to backwards compatibility it won't be fixed, so you may want to use `astropy`'s implementation.

Comment: Just an update for those scrolling through here, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5747 was merged in March 2022, so it seems that this is no longer an issue in SciPy >= 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

This `circvar` according to the docstring

> ... uses a definition of circular variance that in the limit of small
>   angles returns a number close to the 'linear' variance.

In fact, it is the square of `circstd` of which wikipedia says

> ... values between 0 and infinity. This definition of the standard
>   deviation ... is useful because for a wrapped normal distribution, it
>   is an estimator of the standard deviation of the underlying normal
>   distribution. It will therefore allow the circular distribution to be
>   standardized as in the linear case, for small values of the standard
>   deviation. This also applies to the von Mises distribution ...

it also mentions that for small spread the two definitions of circular variance are the same up to a factor of two.

Answer (score 1):

It probably shouldn't be. The calculation for `circstd` looks normal:

```
return ((high - low)/2.0/pi) * sqrt(-2*log(R))
```

The calculation for `circvar` looks wrong though:

```
return ((high - low)/2.0/pi)**2 * 2 * log(1/R)
```

I don't know why it's calculating circular variance as `2*ln(1/R)`. This might be an approximation I've never seen before but I dunno - I'd probably open a bug for this.

Comment: This `var` is just the square of the `std`. I'm not saying this is or isn't appropriate here. Docstring says _"This uses a definition of circular variance that in the limit of small angles returns a number close to the 'linear' variance."_ which is what wikipedia says about the `std` - so that looks ok to me.

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/140 is the pull request where the variance calculation was changed from `1 - R` to `2 * log (1/r)` so that guy might know.

Comment: @CJ59, this guy the founder of numpy and scipy packages!

Answer (score 1):

I developed this code and it always gives me variance between 0-1. Just adapted what I read [here](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Circular_Data_Analysis.pdf).

```
def variance_angle(deg):
    """
    deg: angles in degrees 
    """
    deg = np.deg2rad(deg)
    deg = deg[~np.isnan(deg)]

    S = np.array(deg)
    C = np.array(deg)

    length = C.size

    S = np.sum(np.sin(S))
    C = np.sum(np.cos(C))
    R = np.sqrt(S**2 + C**2)
    R_avg = R/length
    V = 1- R_avg

    return V
```

Answer (score 1):

This code also allows for weighted averages.
It returns both the mean and the variance as defined in the appropriate Wikipedia article.
Calculations are in radiants.

```
def circular_mean(angles, weights=None):
    
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_mean
    
    if weights is None:
        weights = np.ones(len(angles))
        
    vectors = [ [w*np.cos(a), w*np.sin(a)]  for a,w in zip(angles,weights) ]
    
    vector = np.sum(vectors, axis=0) / np.sum(weights)
    
    x,y = vector
    
    angle_mean = np.arctan2(y,x)
    angle_variance = 1. - np.linalg.norm(vector)  # x*2+y*2 = hypot(x,y)
    
    return angle_mean, angle_variance
```

Make sure the sum of weights is positive (not zero) and all weights are non-negative. They do not have to be normalized as this is done in the function by dividing by sum of weights.

Alternatively you could also use `np.average` with weighted average on the unit vectors derived from the angles.

Additionally, keep in mind that there are different conventions on the circular variance.

You can visualize the vectors:

```
plt.scatter(vectors[:,0], vectors[:,1])
plt.scatter([0],[0],color="black")
plt.grid()    
plt.scatter([x],[y])
plt.show()
```